# S3 objects without prefix performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to find out whether storing objects with randomized keys and no "prefix" will give me S3 max performacne of 5500 Get/sec per object or since I don't have a prefix all those objects without prefix fall into a "no-prefix" category and share the 5500 limit.

Example: The following objects are stored directly in a bucket

```
njfoia74G.obj
njfoia74G.obj
njfoia74G.obj
```

will I get 5500 Get/Sec for each object or do they share that?

S3 documentation suggests that ky are not part of the prefix so not sure how to calculate throughput for those objects.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys

Has anyone done a benchmark or have documentation that can answer this?

Comment: If they are stored directly in the bucket then they'll share the 5500 get request limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Request Rate and Performance Guidelines - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html):

> Your application can achieve at least 3,500 PUT/POST/DELETE and 5,500 GET requests per second per prefix in a bucket.

The root of a bucket is effectively an empty prefix, so all objects in the root would share the limit.

By the way very few systems would approach anywhere near these volumes. If you have millions of users (causing over 10 million requests per hour), then definitely implement some of the recommended techniques. But the vast majority of sites will never need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess I should start thinking about adding prefixes since I'll be hitting ~4500GET/sec soon on the next peak, so I better plan for going over 5500 next year's peak traffic.